# SQL Count of two values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with customer name and Status columns. The status column has two values

```
Test
Live
```

The customers appear more than once and can be classed as either test, live or BOTH like below:

```
**Customer |  Status**
Logistics | Test
Logistics | Live
Ample     | Live
```

What I want is a query to give me a **count of the number of distinct customers who fall under both statuses**. So using the above table, I would count customer logistics (since it has both test and live) but not ample (since it is just live).

Any ideas?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE condition1 AND condition2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select customer 
from
    (select customer, max(IsTest) as IsTest , max(IsLive) as IsLive 
     from 
         (select customer, 
              case when status='test' then 1 else 0 end as IsTest,
              case when status='live' then 1 else 0 end as IsLive   
          from table) a
     group by customer) b
where IsTest = 1 and IsLive = 1
```

Comment: that's great, but how would i add this into a query which i am already selecting other columns?

Comment: you can join this query to your existing query to show more cols

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` clause :

```
select Customer, count(*)
from table t
group by Customer
having min(status) <> max(status);
```

If you want it with specific status then include `where` clause :

```
select Customer, count(*)
from table t
where status in ('Test', 'Live')
group by Customer
having count(distinct status) = 2;
```

**EDIT :** If you want other columns too, then i would prefer :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.Customer = t.Customer and t1.status <> t.status);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, what if i am selecting other columns too, can this still hold?

Comment: @Taz. . . If you want one or two columns then include them with `group by`, but i would prefer to use `exists`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by clause to get your desire output.

```
select Customer, count(*)
from table t
group by Customer
having min(status) <> max(status);
```